# Apply default case in if then else in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, stylesheet

I have multi cases and want to apply if then else inside While.. See this situation:

```
<xsl:when test=" $Status != '0'">
    <xsl:element name="FailedRs">
      <xsl:if test="$Status='1'">
                            <Code>111</Code>
                            <MSG>Try Again</MSG>
     </xsl:if>
     <xsl:if test="$Status='2'">
                            <Code>222</Code>
                            <MSG>sorry your request is not valid</MSG>
     </xsl:if>

     <xsl:if test="$Status='3'">
                            <Code>333</Code>
                            <MSG>try later</MSG>
     </xsl:if>

    </xsl:element>

</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:element name="SuccessRs">
        <Code>000</Code>
        <MSG>Success/MSG>

    </xsl:element>
</xsl:otherwise>
```

Status is around 20 status codes. in FailedRs element inside when, I want to add else part in case the response code was not one of the values (1,2,3....20).
How can I apply default case
when I added for example this:

```
<xsl:if test="not($Status='3')">
                                <Code>999</Code>
                                <MSG>weird Error</MSG>
 </xsl:if>
```

It's working fine when the status is not between 1-20, but if it's one of 1-20 it prints two cases
For example if status code was 1 it will print the below:

```
<Code>111</Code>
<MSG>Try Again</MSG> 
<Code>999</Code>
<MSG>weird Error</MSG>
```

It should be this:

```
 <Code>111</Code>
 <MSG>Try Again</MSG>
```

Can someone help me to achieve my goal.

Comment: Do not repost the same question you just asked that was closed as a duplicate.  Improve the question to clarify how the suggested duplicate is doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Realize that there is no `if-then-else`; use `when-otherwise` if you need `else`.  Beyond that it's hard to tell whether you have a logic error or a misunderstanding of the language.

Comment: Finally, note that your unwanted `<Code>999</Code>` output has no representation in your posted code.  To get good help, post a [mcve].

Comment: yes I know I was telling if that part is added to the above code it doesn't print the desired

Comment: Dear kjhughes I checked all questions regarding when-otherwise, I cant find what I'm looking for . so I posted again and cant remove the previous one. can you please help to achieve this

Comment: You can [edit] this question and add a [mcve].